# How do I give certain edges a class?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have a force directed graph where I can show and hide nodes. I wish to do this for the edges based on if the edge source and target are shown or hidden.

Here I am choosing the edge, looping through all the selected nodes to see if any of them match the edges source, if they do, loop through them again to see if they match the edges' target too and then I want to set that edges class to "visible" if it doesn't show both source and target then set class to "hidden".

```
  var selectedNodes = d3.selectAll(".selectedNode"); 
  var linksVisible = d3.selectAll(".link.visible"); 

  var countOfVisibleLinks = [];
  linksVisible.each(function(o)
  {
      selectedNodes.each(function(i)
      {
          if(o.source.index === i.index)
          {
              //clog("yes1");
              selectedNodes.each(function(j)
              {
                  if(o.target.index === j.index)
                  { 
                      countOfVisibleLinks++;
                      //visibleLinks.push(o);

                      var myLink = d3.selectAll(".link.visible")
                                     .classed("hidden", function(d) { 
                                                           return d === o ? false : true;
                                                        });
                      //.filter(function(d) { return d === o; })
                      //.attr('class', 'hidden');

                   }
               })
          } 
      })
  });
```

The 'countOfVisibleLinks' works, as it correctly counts the visible edges, but the function after this doesn't set the chosen ones to 'visible' and the un-chosen ones to 'hidden'

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like

```
d3.selectAll(".link").attr("class", function(d) {
    var c = "link";
    if (d.source.visible && d.target.visible) { // or however you check the nodes?
        c += " visible";
    } else {
        c += " hidden";
    }
    return c;
});
```

For your scenario you might use `if (selectedNodes.indexOf(d.source)...`

Comment: thank you, shall try this tomorrow and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: it works. However instead of if(d.source.visible) i used (d.source.selected) to see if the source and target nodes are selected (i.e visible) rather than finding their classes. Nice work, thankyou